# Scrapy not getting clean text using extract_first()

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape some text from a website under many span tags, but not getting clean text, any help would be appreciated!

Here is the url:

```
https://www.example.com
```

This is what i'm trying

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="agency-header__address"]').extract_first()
```

expected output:

```
Level 18, 25 Bligh Street, SYDNEY, NSW 2000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get required text by extracting *string representation* of the `div`:

```
response.xpath('string(//div[@class="agency-header__address"])').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to grab the xpath `text()` for everything inside your given xpath.
For example:

```
result = response.xpath('//div[@class="agency-header__address"]//text()').extract()
```

This is going to return multiple `span` elements, so you have to use `extract()`.
Then you can join and clean it however you want, maybe like:

```
''.join(result).replace('\xa0', ' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one useful lib for this task (from creators of Scrapy), you should try it: https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/html-text

```
import html_text
i_need_text=response.xpath('//div[@class="agency-header__address"]').extract_first()
html_text.extract_text(i_need_text)
```

Out[4]: 'Level 18, 25 Bligh Street, SYDNEY, NSW 2000'